# Как выйти полностью из приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

изучаю WPF, не могу разобраться с событиями. Сделал событие OnClosing на основном окне и когда пользователь хочет закрыть я его спрашиваю дополнительно об этом и всё работает на главном окне. Но тут парадокс, как мне полностью закрывать приложение, если при  переходе на другие окна я скрываю основное окно и при попытке закрыть приложение со 2 окна, он постоянно попадает в событие OnClosing. Не понимаю как можно это реализовать. Он как бы когда я пытаюсь окна закрыть попадает в события onClosing и из-за этого срабатывает повторная проверка.

```
public void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var exit = MessageBox.Show(
      "Вы действительно хотите закрыть приложение?",
        "Выход из приложения", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (exit == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}

public void ShowWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.MainWindow_OnClosing(sender, e);
}
```

т.е при закрытии не с главного окна - выводится два MessageBox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код полагается прикладывать текстом, а не картинкой )

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Чтобы закрыть приложение, надо просто закрыть все окна.

Comment: Сорри ребят, добавил всё - чтобы было понятнее)

Comment: @SW1pr0g, System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
```

Не надо этого делать. Вы просто таким образом создаете новое окно, копию `MainWindow`, а не взаимодействуете со старым. Основы ООП - не надо путать типы и объекты, познакомьтесь с понятиями "экземпляр класса" и "объект". Класс - это некий шаблон для создания объекта, но не сам объект.

Чтобы обратиться к главному окну, вам нужно передать на него ссылку в дочернее окно при его создании.

```
public partial class ShowWindow
{
    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public ShowWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
}
```

При создании дочернего окна в главном окне, передайте ему ссылку на главное окно.

```
ShowWindow child = new ShowWindow(this);
child.Show();
```

Далее, не надо вызывать обработчик `Closing` явно, вызывайте просто закрытие окна

```
public void ShowWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _mainWindow.Close();
}
```

Здесь возникает вопрос, а как же закрыть текущее окно только тогда, когда главное окно приняло решение закрыться, а вот так:

```
public partial class ShowWindow
{
    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;
    private bool _mainClosed;

    public ShowWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
        // событие Closed вызывается если Closing не было отменено
        _mainWindow.Closed += (s, e) => { _mainClosed = true; this.Close(); }
    }

    public void ShowWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mainClosed)
            return;
        _mainWindow.Close();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Далее, не используйте `Application.Current.Shutdown();` - это плохой код и говорит он о том, что вы не можете в полной мере контролировать свои окна.
Поправьте обработчик вот так.

```
public void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var exit = MessageBox.Show(
        "Вы действительно хотите закрыть приложение?",
        "Выход из приложения", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (exit != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

А вообще познакомьтесь с диалогами, то есть узнайте отличие `.ShowDialog()` от `.Show()`. Возможно и не придется городить такие костыли с обработчиками, чтобы начать нормально контролировать окна.

Подробнее о том, когда и какие события возникают у окна, можно узнать здесь: [Window lifetime events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/#window-lifetime-events).

Comment: Хорошо, тогда вопрос. Почему при вызове Close() он закрывает приложение в разы медленнее, чем если использовать Application.Current.Shutdown()?

Comment: @SW1pr0g откуда ж я знаю, ваш код видите только вы. Мне неизвестно, что там у вас в обработчиках и что там вообще в приложении.